# pyinstaller hidden import rpy2.robjects

Tags: python, pyinstaller, rpy2

has anyone tried to package a python program with rpy2.robjects? It seems that pyinstaller always fail to find this module. Here is what I have:

```
>>> import rpy2.robjects
>>> print rpy2.robjects.__file__
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2-2.3.6-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/rpy2/robjects/__init__.pyc
```

Therefore, in my spec file, I added:

```
hiddenimports=['rpy2.robjects.__init__'],
hookspath=['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2-2.3.6-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/rpy2/robjects']
```

The app crashes after packaging. I am pretty sure this is the only cause of the crash. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: should it not be `hiddenimports=['rpy2.robjects]` ?

Comment: @karthikr I have also tried hiddenimports=['rpy2.robjects'], it didn't work.